# How should I use libfaketime and cron in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, time, cron

I would like to set a Docker container up, which

- fakes a chosen date with libfaketime;
- runs a cron job with that fake time.

My attempt can be found at https://gitlab.com/gablab/proto_docker_cron_libfaketime. The most relevant lines are probably

```
# Dockerfile
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

```
# crontab_for_container
*  *  *  *  * for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; flock -n /.flock_reprio /myscript.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1; sleep 10; done
```

### More details

#### Running the script directly

```
docker-compose exec myservice bash
```

and then `bash /myscript.sh` gives the wanted date. Same for `docker-compose exec myservice date`.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster AS base


RUN set -ex;         \
    apt-get update;  

ADD ./myscript.sh /myscript.sh



RUN apt install -y cron
COPY ./crontab_for_container /etc/cron.d/crontab_for_container 
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab_for_container 
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab_for_container 
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

from base as builder

# faketime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make gcc git 
# Get the sources and checkout at stable release 0.98
# see https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/releases
RUN git clone https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime.git && \
    cd libfaketime && \
    git checkout dc2ae5eef31c7a64ce3a976487d8e57d50b8d594 && \
    make


from base as runtime

COPY --from=builder /libfaketime/src/libfaketime.so.1 /usr/local/lib 
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1
ARG FAKETIME_ARG="0d"
ENV FAKETIME=$FAKETIME_ARG
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant details in the question itself.  You could set `CMD flock -n /.flock_reprio /myscript.sh` to run the command directly without involving cron, or `docker run your-image flock ...` to override the command the container runs when you start it.

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze, I'm interested specifically in running this command with cron. However, I edited adding that running the script directly from bash gives the expected result. Can you be more precise with the details I should add? I'll start with the Dockerfile.

Comment: The complete Dockerfile you included is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick, dirty fix that works is to hard-code into the crontab file the variables to be passed to the job:

```
# crontab
*  *  *  *  * for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i;  LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME=FAKETIME_PLACEHOLDER TEST=ABCD flock -n /.flock_reprio /myscript.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1; sleep 10; done
```

```
# Dockerfile
RUN sed --in-place -e s/FAKETIME_PLACEHOLDER/"\"$FAKETIME_ARG\""/ /etc/cron.d/crontab_for_container
```

(note that the quotes `\"` are needed because the date could be provided as "@2020-02-02 10:00:00").